# Website launching in Worklight iPhone App WL Object is not defined

Tags: iphone, ibm-mobilefirst, undefined

I am having an issue. Here is the background of App. Currently, I am opening website into Worklight App. So, my all declarations of WL(object) are defined at website. Because of having the same structure of resources website opened in worklight app suppose to be working fine. My app is working good in Android but for iPhone it's not detecting WL object.

Any Ideas?

Comment: The explanation is not good. I don't understand what you did.

Comment: ok let me tell you ... I am currently opening external website into my application. On external website I have copied all the resources/files like common folder in worklight.
The issue I am facing is when I call the external website into me application WL object (i.e WL.Client.Connect) works fine in android but not in iPhone. The error occurs that WL is not defined
Let me know, Idan if you need more clarifications

Comment: Why are you working like that? Are you basing this on some guide?

Comment: Idan- the scenario is we are currently integrating Mobile app with external website. The reason of calling external web within application is that, client does changes in their web on weekly basis and due to lack of WL expertise at client side it would be difficult to manage WL code. So, the problem is remain the same as I told you. your help would be really grateful

Comment: This is not what I asked. Are you following some guide for this integration?

Comment: no Idan there isn't any guide to follow. we have developed this idea.

Comment: ?? Any Idea till now

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing, "loading worklight in an external website" is really not a supported scenario and not how MobileFirst was meant to be used. I am surprised it is working in Android at all.

The way you can load a "remote worklight-based 'app'" in your existing mobilefirst application is by using one of the following approaches:

- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/using-a-mobilefirst-application-as-a-container-for-server-generated-pages/
- https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/documentation/getting-started-7-1/foundation/advanced-topics/container-advanced-pages/